# Yahoo! blocked my Yahoo! Answers account - How to delete answers posted by me

Tags: yahoo-answers

Yahoo! has blocked my Yahoo! Answers account (I am able to use all other services of the same Yahoo Account) because I posted answers such as "Ask this question on stackexchange.com"; now I do not wish to regain my account, but I want to be able to delete a few questions and answers posted by me on Yahoo! Answers; is there any way I can do that?

Is it contacting Yahoo! is the only way out here? Or is there something I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only delete open question or answers, if they have gone to the vote or resolved they cannot be removed. Even if they are open, you need to be logged in to delete them.

The questions and answers stay in Yahoo archive available for searching and browsing. Only Yahoo! itself can delete them.

Answer (score -2):

Use other yahoo accounts to flag your own answers as being(chat)